# I want to remove three strings from a table in qlikview. LIKE LPA,lpa AND INR

Tags: qlikview

```
1.2lpa    
2 LPA      
INR 20000.
```

These are  the records available and i need only numerical by triming the rest . What function and logic could be applied?

```
Replace(CurrentCTC, 'LPA' , '' ).
```

But the above function removes only `LPA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `KeepChar` function in your case. The function accept chars which should be kept after it

`KeepChar(CurrentCTC, '0123456789')`

You can read more about this function in Qlik's help page about [KeepChar](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/StringFunctions/KeepChar.htm)

Comment: now i have one problem. All the records that i want should be in  terms of 12,2, or 12.5 which indicates 12 LPA, 2LAP or 12.5 LPA. We had INR 200000,500000,etc. Now in that same column i need the above values to 2 ,5 etc. LIke any values larger 6 digits divide by 100000. KeepChar(CurrentCTC, '0123456789') also this function removed decimal point , so how to solve that too

Comment: KeepChar(CurrentCTC, '0123456789.0') This brought the values with decimals back.

Comment: You dont need the second 0 (the one at the end). This function dont care about the format of your string. It will just keep all the characters listed.